# How to calculate sum for a specific facet ranges in solr hybris?

Tags: solr, sap-commerce-cloud

How to calculate sum for a specific facet ranges in solr hybris?

We have to calculate sum of amounts for duedate(duedate_date) falling under date ranges of gap 30 days.

```
  For eg : For 30 days from today , we have to find sum of amount . Days are determined using duedate_date field
```

{
"id":"cat1",
"amount_double":100,
"duedate_date":"2023-05-11T03:00:00Z",
"*root*":"cat1"
},
{
"id":"cat2",
"amount_double":200,
"duedate_date":"2023-06-11T03:00:00Z",
"*root*":"cat2"
},
{
"id":"cat3",
"amount_double":300,
"duedate_date":"2023-07-01T03:00:00Z",
"*root*":"cat3"
},
{
"id":"cat4",
"amount_double":400,
"duedate_date":"2023-08-11T03:00:00Z",
"*root*":"cat4"
},

```
    output:
    
    -30days from today = 100(cat1)
    +30days from today = 500(cat2+cat3)
    30 to 60 days = 400(cat4)
    
    current output :
    
    sending date calculating and fetching total amount using stats and stats.field
    
    Required :
    
    Want to implement facet.range(facet.range.gap=+30DAY) and calculate sum
```